# How to float an image in the header over a carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a company logo inside the header panel and it is taller than the height of its parent container (by design).

Below the header panel is a carousel. To understand this better, kindly check the link below for the image.

[image]

As you can see in the sample image, I want the logo to be on top of the carousel. When I tried it, the carousel is on top of the logo and not behind it.

Here is my codes.

```css
.navbar.navbar-default {
    border: none;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    border-top: 3px solid #001f36;
}


.navbar-header {
    height: 100%;
}

.navbar-brand {
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: -3px;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" title="Test Logo"><img src="/Images/main-logo.png" alt="Test Logo" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Dropdown 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dropdown 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


<--CAROUSEL-->
  
<div id="carousel-container">
    <div id="body-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="http://blog.eastfist.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/nikonD5100_img_05_l.jpg" alt="Chania">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://cdn0.mos.techradar.futurecdn.net/Review%20images/PhotoRadar/Nikon/Nikon%20D5100/miniature.jpg" alt="Chania">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d4/img/sample/img_03_l.jpg" alt="Flower">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="img_flower2.jpg" alt="Flower">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Left and Right Buttons-->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#body-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#body-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any image on the first instance plus you need to add your code for better understanding or create a demo for proper solutions.

Comment: Add the HTML and CSS please

Comment: Image is not enough. You should add HTML and CSS. Cause its depending on the CSS of the nav bar and the logo

Comment: @XahedKamal The post is already updated.

Comment: Can you use fixed height for the navigation bar's container?

Comment: @XahedKamal Yeah, I tried but it didn't work for me. Someone has answered my question below, vanburenx. Thank you for your reply. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are trying to do based on the posted image. You can use display:block and change the z-index of the `navbar-brand` class to float your logo over the carousel. See working example.

```css
.navbar.navbar-custom {
  border: none;
  background: red;
  border-top: 3px solid #001f36;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-brand img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: white;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-right > li,
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-right .dropdown-menu > li {
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/150x75/128236/fff?text=Logo" alt="Test Logo" />
        </a>

      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="dropdown"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown<span class="caret"></span></a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown 1</a>

              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown 2</a>

              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</div>
<div id="carousel-container">
  <div id="body-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/2550x500/266080" alt="Chania">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/2550x500/266080" alt="Chania">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/2550x500/266080" alt="Flower">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/2550x500/266080" alt="Flower">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Left and Right Buttons-->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#body-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#body-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is it. Thank you so much!